# jQuery: Adding XML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

**Update**
New code gave me `DOM Exception 8` error.

```
if($('#searchClientName').val() != '')
{
   $($.parseXML(requestXML)).find('Parameters').get(0).appendChild('<ClientName>'+$('#searchClientName').val()+'</ClientName>');
}
```

**I tried using these options too:**

1. `$('<ClientName>'+$('#searchClientName').val()+'</ClientName>').appendTo($($.parseXML(requestXML)).find('RequestParameters').get(0));`
2. It doesn't give any error but XML remains unchanged.

   xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                           clientNameElement = xmlDoc.createElement('ClientName');
                           clientNameValue = xmlDoc.createTextNode($('#searchClientName').val());
                           clientNameElement.appendChild(clientNameValue);
   $($.parseXML(requestXML)).find('RequestParameters').get(0).appendChild(clientNameElement);

**Old Code:**
I am having hard time doing the XML manipulation with jQuery.
Not able to figure out how to implement commented part:

```
var requestXML = "<Request><Type>Search</Type><Parameters></Parameters></Request>",
    requestDoc = $.parseXML(requestXML),
    reqXML = $( requestDoc ),
    $parameters = $reqXML.find('Parameters');

    if($('#clientNameTextField').val() != '')
    {
        //Add <ClientName> name text field value</ClientName><ParameterType>ClientName</ParameterType>
    }
    else if ($('#idTextField').val() != '')
    {
        //Add <ClientId> id text field value</ClientId><ParameterType>ClientId</ParameterType>
    }
```

> Note: Camel casing is important for element names

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

**Updated** the code as to maintain Camel Case for node names.

```
var requestXML = "<Request><Type>Search</Type><Parameters></Parameters></Request>",
    $reqXML = $( jQuery.parseXML(requestXML) ),
    $parameters = $reqXML.find('Parameters');

    if($('#clientNameTextField').val() != '')
    {
        //Add <ClientName> name text field value</ClientName><ParameterType>ClientName</ParameterType>
        $parameters.append(jQuery.parseXML('<ClientName>Apple</ClientName>').documentElement);
        $parameters.append(jQuery.parseXML('<ParameterType>P999</ParameterType>').documentElement);
    }
    else if ($('#idTextField').val() != '')
    {
        //Add <ClientId> id text field value</ClientId><ParameterType>ClientId</ParameterType>
        $parameters.append(jQuery.parseXML('<ClientId>C111</ClientId>').documentElement);
        $parameters.append(jQuery.parseXML('<ParameterType>P999</ParameterType>').documentElement);
    }

    var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($reqXML.get(0));
    console.log(xmlString);
```

Comment: This implementation is loosing all camel casing of the element names. Pleas check my Note.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I updated my example accordingly. It will now support specific case.